# Query for amount of upvotes per month on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, upvotes, data-explorer

Does anyone have a query for Stack Overflow's database to get the total amount of upvotes (on Stack Overflow) month by month? Just thinking about it makes my head hurt. (SEDE)

Comment: Related (cross-site): *[SEDE query for questions asked per month (help needed)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/289731)*

Comment: :P my own question related to another one of my questions

Comment: @ChristopherPeart: Yes, because you basically cross-posted it.

Comment: @PeterMortensen -  I don't see any particular relationship between the questions except they are both about querying SEDE and posted by the same user. The questions asked are not the same. (What do the PostTypeID mean? vs How to get monthly upvotes and downvotes)

Comment: @lxg Where is the cross post?

Comment: Ok, maybe not exactly cross-posted, but they both refer to things that can be researched by oneself through SEDE. On SO, I would consider such a question being “too broad”. If one is struggling building the SEDE query, they should point out what they’ve tried so far and where excactly they got stuck.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You mean something like [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/615200/number-of-upvotes-per-month-in-one-year#graph)? (thanks for the improvement, @CodyGray)
It's about 1.4 million upvotes each month; the number of downvotes is about a factor 7 lower.

[image]

For reference, here is the complete query:

```sql
SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, M, 0) AS Month,
       ( 1 - GROUPING(M) ) * SUM(IIF(VoteTypeId = 2, 1, 0)) AS UpVotes,
       ( 1 - GROUPING(M) ) * SUM(IIF(VoteTypeId = 3, 1, 0)) AS DownVotes
FROM   Votes
       CROSS APPLY (VALUES (DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, CreationDate))) V(M)
WHERE  VoteTypeId IN ( 2, 3 )
       AND CreationDate >= '2016-01-01'
       AND CreationDate < '2017-01-01'
GROUP  BY GROUPING SETS ( ( ), ( M ) )
```

Note that SEDE is updated once a week, on Sunday morning.

Comment: Very misleading to include January 2017 in the graph…even though you did mention it in the text. How about [this](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/614630/number-of-upvotes-per-month-in-one-year#graph) instead?

Comment: *There are lies, damn lies, and SEDE graphs ...*

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I wanted (and more). I was worried about getting flagged!

Comment: The tracks by CreationDate. Shouldn't that mean that - and it appears to me to be the case - the older a question the more votes? If today I up vote something created last March, correct? I imagine it's not a major trending curve, but that would also explain why December's count is the lowest.

Comment: CreationDate is the creation date of the vote, not the post. December is the lowest because it's holiday season.

Comment: @Glorfindel *There are lies, damn lies, and [graphs not starting at zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Misleading_graph#Truncated_graph)…*

Comment: I know. The old one was better in that regard, but it still didn't start at zero.

Comment: @AntonSamsonov also, check this [Cross Validated question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/184525/how-to-determine-whether-or-not-the-y-axis-of-a-graph-should-start-at-zero).

Comment: @Glorfindel The accepted answer for that topic says: “Show zero on the *y* axis if comparisons with zero are central to the problem, or even of some interest”, — that is totally the case for graphs like above, i. e. “popularity” graphs, as we naturally compare popularity rates with each other and against “no popularity at al” (which is zero). In fact, 1325000 is 88 % of 1500000, yet the graph above depicts it more like 30 %.

Comment: I don't really agree that comparing against 0 is vital; the OP just asks for a number. Furthermore, **I can't change the graph**, it comes directly from SEDE. You can propose a [feature-request] to have this changed.

Comment: OK, @MartinSmith, I stand corrected. But it's non-trivial...

Comment: @AntonSamsonov there is a pleasant mix of all three shown at my quarterly company-wide meetings. It's a recurring joke that gives us all a little chuckle.

Comment: My upvote to downvote ratio is probably the opposite of the site average. I'm amazed at those stats considering the quality of questions on SO.

Comment: Upvotes on questions are free (no reputation loss), and a user can cast upvotes at a much lower reputation threshold than they can downvotes. The stats are quite believable, though still backwards from the way it should be. @turnip

Comment: Good point. I'd forgotten about the min-rep level for downvotes.

Comment: I'm not sure that the upvote/downvote ratio is *"backwards from how it should be"*, as @CodyGray puts it. Yes, there are more bad questions than good ones, but questions with more views get more votes, and good questions get more views (sometimes many orders of magnitudes more) than bad ones. There's a cynical explanation for the ratio here, which is that crap content gets upvoted by idiots, but also a hopeful one, which is that Google is so good at channelling users to high-quality content that the average page view here is 7 times more likely to be good than bad. I don't know which is true.