# Why did I get a warning about badly received questions and how can I fix it?

Tags: support, post-ban

## I am *not* banned from asking questions

So I received a warning about past questions not being well received and getting a question ban. What questions did I mess up on? I had one that I removed as it was a bad question but that was months ago. My most recent questions are being well received on Stack Exchange ([SEDE query for questions asked per month (help needed)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/289731/sede-query-for-questions-asked-per-month-help-needed) and [Query for amount of upvotes per month on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341324/query-for-amount-of-upvotes-per-month-on-stack-overflow)?) So what why did I get this warning and how do I fix it?

Comment: Are you getting that warning on the main site?

Comment: I am not banned. I can go ask a question. I am asking about the warning as this is my first warning from mods that I know of

Comment: hence why I edited my comment ;). Anyway it's not from a mod. It's automated. You have to look at the site where you got the warning and focus there. If the warning is on stack overflow, SE or metaSO will not help

Comment: Yeah I got it on SO and can't find any questions that are not well received besides a very one and removed one.

Comment: If it is on so... Then you HAVE to have some pretty horrendous deleted stuff... All I can see is positive. And sorry to disagree, but there has to be more than ONE deleted question there. Or it was a truly horrible one, with a bunch of answers on or something... Or something really changed in the script

Comment: My only removed question is not that bad. I wrote and answered my self.

Comment: Well again.... The script simply isn't that sensitive... Something else has to be going on.

Comment: Well I checked and it was -8 before I removed it. Everything else is normal

Comment: Maybe you were trying to answer and got a warning there? AFAIK one -8 shouldn't get you banned....

Comment: I was just asking a question. I am not banned. I have the warning however

Comment: @Patrice He's *not* banned, just being warned.  One bad question can't get you banned, but I'm not sure that it couldn't get you a warning.

Answer (score 1):

This question is overly broad, even for meta, so here's an overly general answer:

1. Navigate to your question list
2. Sort the list by votes
3. Navigate to the last page
4. Select the last question in the list
5. Evaluate that question and determine whether or not it is salvageable

   - if so, select the next item in the list, repeat until a salvageable question is found
6. Ask on meta how you can improve that question
7. Apply the advice you receive to that question
8. Apply what you've learned to the rest of your questions
9. Rinse and repeat

---

Another thing to keep in mind is that the automated system does not care if content is deleted or not. Deleting poorly received content will not change anything with regard to the automated system.

If there are any posts that are unsalvageable, heavily downvoted, and you've learned your lesson, you can [request disassociation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323395/4639281) of the content from your account.

---

If you have content that was deleted more than 60 days ago and do not have 10K rep, you can use the **"contact us"** link at the bottom of every page, or ask a moderator for a list of your deleted content.

If you have content that was deleted more than 60 days ago and you do have 10K rep, you can search using `deleted:1` to find your own deleted content.